# Regression with distribution as y variable rather than a single value?

Tags: r, regression, distributions

I am interested in examining the relationship of `X` on `Y`. Both `X` and `Y` are continuous variables. I expect the relationship is linear. I know I can do a simple linear regression here, however I'm curious if I could do something a bit different to make a more informed inference.

The `Y` values are themselves estimated parameters from another test. I have an estimated mean and standard deviation for each `Y` value (from normal distributions). Could I use the whole probability distribution from each `Y` observation rather than just the mean estimate when examining `Y`'s relationship with `X`? The standard deviations for different `Y` values can vary quite a bit, so I think it could be interesting to see how their distributions may overlap and combine and whether that will affect the statistical relationship between `X` and `Y`.

Does anyone know what kind of test I can do to examine this? I'm analyzing my data in R.

Here's a brief sketch trying to illustrate my situation. Note that each `Y` observation is a distribution (not just the one I pointed out).

[image: sketch]

**EDIT**

If it helps, I could also make `X` a distribution rather than a single value, but it would not be normally distributed. For each observation `Y`, there are 100s to 1000s of `X` observations that I'm averaging to get the single `X` value to examine in this relationship. Rather than averaging them to get a single `X` value, I could work with the whole distribution of observations.

If that broadens the range of statistical tests that are available then I can do that too. If it doesn't make a difference, I can just use average values as well.

Comment: Please search our site for "weighted regression".  You might also include "variance" as a search term.

Comment: Are you suggesting weighted regression due to my comment on standard deviations varying? Note that I'm referring to the SD for the estimates that compose each individual `Y` observation. I don't think there's much heteroscedasticity in the regression residuals of `Y~X`...

Comment: The variances of the Y's will contribute to the variances of the regression residuals.  Thus some form of weighted regression looks like a good option.